# deparse and substitute on ellipsis to get names of parameters

Tags: r, function, ellipsis

How do I get the names of paramaters used for ellipsis in a function call, independent whether they are packed into a list or not?

The following function works pretty fine if the parameters are passed directly into the function.

```
foo <- function(...) {
  sapply(substitute(...()), deparse)
}

a <- 1:3
b <- 2:6
foo(a, b)

result: "a" "b"
```

Now I pack the parameters explicitly into a list, to make my code more pipe-friendly:

```
foo(list(a, b))

result: "list(a, b)"
```

The function foo should also work with that, to return only the names a and b. How to handle this within function foo?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you always plan to literally use `list()` when calling with more than one variable? You never want to use `x <- list(a, b); foo(x)` for example? Trying to do stuff that requires non-standard evaluation with no alternative for more programmatic interaction is typically a recipe for headaches later on.

Comment: In principle, I totally agree with you. I usually design clear interfaces so that there are no headaches later. However, if ellipsis is the first parameter of a function, I would also like to allow a pipe-friendly usage of the function. And in this case I think a list is the easiest way.

Comment: I assume you are only targeting the native pipe `|>` and not `%>%`? Because with the latter you cannot pipe in unevaluated symbols. `list(a,b) |> foo()` would be quite different from `list(a,b) %>% foo()`

Comment: Yes! Considering a pipe-friendly usage helps me a lot of dealing with same situations  in a really smart way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a workaround try this

```
foo <- function(...) {
    x <- substitute(...())
    if(class(x[[1]]) == "call")  sapply(x[[1]][-1] , deparse)
    else sapply(x , deparse)
}
```

- Output

```
> foo(list(a, b))
[1] "a" "b"

> foo(a, b)
[1] "a" "b"
```